# Opening Notepad on remote system using RMI

Tags: java, ssh, rmi

I am trying to use RMI to open notepad in the remote system.
Is it possible to do that using RMI??
Or do I have to use SSH ??

Comment: RMI is just an API. You can do anything that java VM allows you to do.

Answer (score 1):

Comparing RMI with SSH is a bit like comparing apples with oranges. RMI is more of a general purpose API for performing requests over the network, while SSH is a program used to establish a secure shell connection over which you can send shell commands.

To open Notepad on a remote host, you can use either RMI or SSH since both are capable of communicating over the network.

In either case, you'll need a server on the receiving end, that handles your commands and opens Notepad for you. If you use SSH, this will be readily available to you, in the form of an `sshd` daemon. In case you go for RMI I don't know of any predefined server implementation. I would recommend you to write up your own server serving your particular requests.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your prompt reply. My knowledge in RMI or SSH is very limited. 
And I do plan to write my own set of code as I am trying to make an application. Could you please suggest me the command for it?
ActiveX commands don't work on mozilla. Thanks. :)